# How do I stop this code from throwing error 10053?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sockets

im following along with *techwithtim's* tutorial on making an *mmorpg* and i have the following code hand copied from video 4. all of this happens on the same computer with firewall and *bitdefender* disabled.

https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/python-online-game-tutorial/connecting-multiple-clients/

I run `gamerun`:

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import sys

server='192.168.142.1'
port=5555

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
  s.bind((server,port))
except socket.error as e:
  str(e)

s.listen(2)
print("waiting...")

def read_pos(str):
  str=str.split(',')
  return int(str[0]),int(str[1])
def make_pos(tup):
  return str(tup[0])+','+str(tup[1])

pos=[(0,0),(100,100)]
def threaded_client(conn, player):
  conn.send(str.encode(make_pos(pos[player])))
  reply=''
  while True:
    try:
      data=read_pos(conn.recv(2048).decode())
      pos[player]=data
      print(player)
      if not data:
        print('dc')
        break
      else:
        print('yay')
        if player == 1:
          reply=pos[0]
        else:
          reply=pos[1]
          
        print('rcv:',data)
        print('snd:',reply)
      conn.sendall(str.encode(make_pos(reply)))
    except:
      break
  print('lost conn')
  conn.close()

currentPlayer=0
while True:
  conn, addr=s.accept()
  print("connected to:", addr)

  start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,currentPlayer))
  currentPlayer+=1
```

then i run the following, copied into two differently named files because it was causing issues. called 'game'

```
from talkydaemon import talky

width=500
height=500
win=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

clientNumber=0

class Player():
  def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.width=width
    self.height=height
    self.color=color
    self.rect=x,y,width,height
    self.vel=.5

  def draw(self,win):
    pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

  def move(self):
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
      self.x-=self.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      self.x+=self.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
      self.y-=self.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
      self.y+=self.vel

    self.update()
  def update(self):
    self.rect=(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)

def read_pos(str):
  str=str.split(',')
  return int(str[0]),int(str[1])
def make_pos(tup):
  return str(tup[0])+','+str(tup[1])

def redrawWindow(win,player,player2):
  win.fill((255,255,255))
  player.draw(win)
  player2.draw(win)
  pygame.display.update()

def main():
  run=True
  t=talky()
  pstart=read_pos(t.getPos())
  p=Player(pstart[0],pstart[1],100,100,(0,255,255))
  p2=Player(0,0,100,100,(0,255,255))
  
  while run:

    p2pos=(100,100)
    print('catch '+t.send(make_pos((p.x,p.y))))
    p2.x=p2pos[0]
    p2.y=p2pos[1]
    p2.update
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
        run=False
        pygame.quit()

    p.move()
    redrawWindow(win,p,p2)

main()
```

which is making calls to talkydaemon:

```
import socket

class talky:
  def __init__(self):
    self.client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server='192.168.142.1'
    self.port=5555
    self.addr=(self.server,self.port)
    self.pos=self.connect()
    print(self.pos)

  def connect(self):
    try:
      self.client.connect(self.addr)
      return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
    except:
      pass
  def send(self, data):
    try:
      self.client.send(str.encode(data))
      return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
    except socket.error as e:
      return str(e)
  def getPos(self):
    return self.pos
```

is this a problem with the code or my OS? i have tried disabling bitdefender and windows firewall and it still behaves the same.

i get the following in my console for game:

```
catch 0,0
catch 0,0...
```

and then as soon as i move in either client:

````
catch [WinError 10053] An establish connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
catch [WinError 10053] An establish connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
catch [WinError 10053] An establish connection was aborted by the software in your host machine...```

while the other client continues to spit positions. where can i look?
````

Comment: Firewall on the client?

Comment: @Klaus D. i turned protection off on bitdefender and i disabled firewall on public/private/domain. am i missing something?

Comment: Well, you know the computer best and remember that our topic here is software development.

Comment: @Klaus D. ok, so this is surely a firewall or something not related to my code or python closing the connection?